# Java VisualVM not able to connect to Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jvisualvm

`Java VisualVM` not able to connect Jboss server, when jboss server running with option `-b 0.0.0.0`.

jboss run script - `run.sh -c web -b 0.0.0.0`

When i try to run jboss with this like - `run.sh -c web -b {MyIp}`

then Java VisualVM is able to connect jboss server.

Can any one help me how to connect while jboss running with first option `( -b 0.0.0.0)`

I am using this configuration in `run.conf` file in jboss

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=256m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8077 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `JAVA_OPTS`

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=256m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8077 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0"
```

instead of `0.0.0.0` use your system `IP`.